# What is the OST that plays during the O & P cinematic battle scene?

Tags: game-music-identification, xenoblade-chronicles-3

What is the name of the OST that plays during O & P cinematic battle scene (the scene I am referring to can be found [here](https://youtu.be/NvneuM6OK70?t=376)<sup>1</sup>)? Any search results always leads me to the OST that plays while you are fighting them, not the OST that plays during this cutscene

---

<sup>1</sup> Major spoiler warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know most of the game's OST yet, but luckily I believe you picked one we do: [The Weight of Life](https://www.xenoserieswiki.org/wiki/The_Weight_of_Life).

Comment: An ha, that’s it. Thanks!